# How do I write a regular expression to match numbers with or without leading zeros AND exclude numbers with certain text?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract measurements from file names, and they are very inconsistent; for example:

- FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00
- FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5P
- FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00SS316

I have to be able to match all numbers (with decimals and with without leading zeros). I think I have that working with this:

```
/\d*\.?\d+/i
```

However, I also want to be able to exclude numbers preceded by SS or GR. Something like this seems to partial work:

```
/(?<!GR|SS)\d*\.?\d+/i
```

That will exclude the 5 from FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5P above but anything more than a single digit is not excluded so 16 from the 316 would be a match. I am doing this in ruby.

Comment: You want to catch a _single_ digit after `GR|SS`?

Comment: The entire number. This is already catching a single digit. So if I had FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5.16P I would want to exclude 5.16.

Comment: Your explanation is inconsistent with your regex, so any attempt to figure out what you mean is lost. Can you 1. show a complete string. 2. Highlight a complete string with what you want to match, and show what shouldn't match?

Comment: Don't try to do all your matching with a single regex.  Match against the first one that checks for the digits you want, and then match against another one to be sure that it does NOT include the stuff you DON'T want.  It will probably be much clearer for the reader.

Comment: It's best to do this in two steps, unless you are cranking these conversions 24/7 and don't have free cycles to burn.  it's good to be elegant and learn kata, it's great not to fail in timely deliverables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have to dither floating number strings its not a trivial feat.
This just takes your last regex and adds some extra stuff to the lookbehind.
This secures that the engine won't bypass a number just to match the regex.

```
 #  (?<!GR)(?<!SS)(?<![.\d])\d*\.?\d+

 # (?<! GR | SS | [.\d] )
 (?<! GR )
 (?<! SS )
 (?<! [.\d] )
 \d* \.? \d+
```

Perl test case

```
 @ary = (
   'FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00 ',
   'FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5P',
   'FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00SS316'
 );

 foreach $fname (@ary)
 {
    print "filename:  $fname\n";
    while ( $fname =~ /(?<!GR)(?<!SS)(?<![.\d])\d*\.?\d+/ig ) {

       print " found $&\n";
    }
 }
```

Output >>

```
 filename:  FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00
  found .5
  found 13
  found 1.00
 filename:  FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5P
  found .5
  found 13
  found 1.00
 filename:  FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00SS316
  found .5
  found 13
  found 1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the SS and GR exclusion, try this:

```
/(?<!GR|SS)[\d\.]+/i
```

I'm not sure exactly what your layout is, but using this would be faster for your negative look behind:

```
(?<![GRS]{2})
```

Edit: the `+` still isn't greedy enough.

You might need to use two regex. One to remove the GR/SS numbers, and one to match (note: I'm not very familiar with Ruby):

```
val.gsub('/[GRS]{2}[\d\.]+/', '')
val =~ /[\d\.]+/
```

Comment: That seems to give me the same result. It excludes the 5 in 'FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00GR5P' but it gives me 16 back in FSTCAR.5_13UNC_1.00SS316. So it does seem to exclude the number directly after GR or SS, but not the entire string.

Comment: I've been testing it and getting the same result. The `+` isn't greedy enough.

Comment: Removing the unwanted numbers first works for this purpose. I might have to stick with 'GR|SS', because I am expecting that I will have to add more prefixes.